# How do i sort or list all "pending" Status

Tags: php

I'm able to list all of my Transaction Logs, so next is how do i list all Pending Status.

This is the code for getting the Total List of Orders regardless of Pending and Claimed Status.

DB Output:

[image: the output of db]

My DataBase:

[image: this is my database img]

```
public function getTotalOrderList()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from tbl_orderlist ORDER BY orderID DESC");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $row );
    }
```

Comment: Select * from table where status = 'Pending' order by column name desc

Comment: ohhh darn thanks it worksss thanksss ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from tbl_orderlist WHERE status = 'Pending' ORDER BY orderID DESC
```