# How do I sum the total of the column which is their status is only Pending

Tags: php

I have this code to get the total of the price column though i want it to only sum the total of those who are in the status of "Claimed"

```
public function getAllSales()
{
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("Select sum(Price) AS total From tbl_orderlist");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
return $result;


}
```

[ClaimedList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nGmt.png)

Comment: same homework as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439641/how-do-i-sort-or-list-all-pending-status

Comment: @Dagon what a shame...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered almost the same question earlier... LOL

```
Select COUNT(*) as total From tbl_orderlist WHERE status = 'Claimed';
```

Comment: i suspect its no coincidence.

Comment: Guess it's the new requirement at school.. Any questions, go to stackoverflow.. haha

Comment: i got a total of 3 D:

Comment: well, is that a good or a bad thing? Maybe you should start by learning how to use the queries? There are a lot of basic tutorials for that online instead of finding easy answers in here.

Comment: solved!!! $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("Select sum(Price) AS total From tbl_orderlist WHERE status = 'Claimed'");